# when should i use creational design Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Creational design patterns are concerned with the way of creating objects. These design patterns are used when a decision must be made at the time of instantiation of a class (i.e. creating an object of a class).

But everyone knows an object is created by using new keyword in java. For example:

```
StudentRecord s1=new StudentRecord();
```

Hard-Coded code is not the good programming approach. Here, we are creating the instance by using the new keyword.

**The above content is from a website**

This says we should refrain from using `new keyword` and use interfaces instead.so that our code is loosely bound.

Factory Pattern Or Abstract Factory Pattern Use interfaces for creating Objects. Singleton also comes in Creational Pattern, but we dont use interfaces in that for creating Object, instead we use `getinstance` method.
that return object using new keyword. if object already exist if return the same object.

How come singleton is Creation Pattern. 
Please explain in brief, when would i use creational pattern.

Comment: "we should refrain from using new keyword" ... so, how do you expect to create instances of classes?

Comment: @Stultuske that is exactly what am not getting.

Comment: "The above content is from a website". Is that website reliable? Sounds like poorly worded advice that might be from good intentions. As a developer you hard code a lot of things, so should you just stop writing code? Obviously not. There are things that you should never hard code (let's say access credentials), things that you *can* hard code, and variations in between.

Comment: @AshishUpadhyay in a Singleton, you use getInstance to get the instance instead of the new keyword, that is correct, but, either the instance already exists and is returned, or the singleton will run myInstance = new MyInstance(); return myInstance; -> the new keyword is still used there

Comment: @Stultuske i know that, in get instance method we use new keyword, the question is when should i use  creational pattern?

Comment: when you need it. for instance: why would you use a Singleton if there is no problem with having multiple instances? for a connection to a DB, sure, you can use a Singleton, but I wouldn't recommend creating a Person class as a Singleton, unless you assume your System can never work knowing about more than one person. There are several creational patterns, but it's up to you to decide on the benefits

Answer (score -1):

Singleton pattern says there will be only one instance of a class no matter how many clients are making use of that class. This pattern dictates that the creation of object of that class should be restricted. This could be to avoid putting the system in an invalid state due to concurrent usage. You could apply this pattern by hard-coding; simply making the constructor private and an abstract public method for retrieving the instance, which should create one if there isn't one created already. Or you can let `Spring` deal with the creation of the objects (if you are using `Spring` of course.

The bottom-line is that Singleton is indeed a creation pattern that developers can adopt if needed.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, which seems to be "when should I use creational pattern".

Comment: It's not the only creational pattern, so in best, this answer is incomplete

Comment: I didn't say it's the only one did I? I said it is a creation pattern @Stultuske

Comment: the question is: "when should I use A(ny) creation pattern", not when should I use a singleton